# Java Collection Framework Set compared to mathematical Set?

Tags: java, collections, set

I am learning Java Collection Framework, and stared with JDK documentation for the same. One of the particular concept which I got confused with is  `Set` interface.

I understood that with `Set` it won't allow duplicate elements to be inserted.

My question is, is Java collections framework Set interface a representation of mathematical Set in anyways?

Comment: Note that `Set` does "allow" duplicate elements to be inserted (it doesn't cause an exception to be thrown); the element simply won't be stored in the set since an equivalent object is already present.

Answer (score 3):

The collections framework version of Set is a reasonably honest representation of *finite* mathematical sets (although not infinite sets). The requirement that an item should only be in a given set once is consistent with [set theory](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222072410/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65580.html).

The mathematical construct that allows the same item more than once is a [multi-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), not a set.

Comment: Nitpick: A `Set` _could_ contain multiple references to the same element, if those elements have (intentionally) wrong implementations of `hashcode` and `equals` methods, or if the element is mutable.

Comment: @tobias_k I think that ignoring edge cases like classes that intentionally violate the contract for `hashCode` and `equals` is probably appropriate for a discussion of this level, don't you?

Comment: Well, I said it's a nitpick, but I thought it worth to mention. After all, could also e.g. end up with two references to the same list in a set if that list got modified in between.

Answer (score 2):

> Is Java collections framework Set interface a representation of
>   mathematical Set in anyways?

Yes, the `Set` interface models the mathematical set abstraction. The following methods can be used to perform some of the common `Set` operations.

**[`addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-)** (set union)

**[`retainAll(Collection<?> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-)** (set intersection)

**[`removeAll(Collection<?> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-)** (set difference)

Comment: Thanks for the answer; so does it mean it would support mathematical operations like : n(AUB) etc? I am not clear on why there is need of Set at all. Could you help in understanding this?

Comment: @CuriousMind yes you can do `(AUB)` by doing `set1.addAll(set2)`.in java, you'd mainly want to use a `Set` to disallow duplicates but there are also other benefits.

Comment: One of the key benefits is cheaply (often with O(1) cost) determining if an object is in a set — this operation is much faster with sets than lists. Another is when order isn't semantically relevant, such as expressing the concept "these are all the people I know at work". Yet another is the Java idiom of using sets of enums as an alternative to int-based flags. (This is common enough that it has its own support class: java.util.EnumSet)